# ATGC sequence of gene expression data

Tags: dataset, genetics, sequence-analysis

I am not a pro in genetics so please excuse my non-technical language.

I need dataset which  contains the gene expression as well as the associated ATGC sequence with each gene expression value. For example if the gene expression for XYZ gene for a subject is 0.032, what is the ATCG sequence associated with it. What  I expect is that sequence  would be like ATCGAGATCGATATGCCATTAGCTATGC.....

So if I have 1000 genes and 10 subjects, I would expect a 1000x10 gene expression matrix and 10000 ATGC sequences in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [GEO database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/)? You'll find a plethora of datasets there, also combinations of gene expression data and sequence data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but as I said, I  am very new to this area. Could you please give me a specific example here. GEO confuses me.